# GCP Organization policy constraint list

Tags: google-cloud-platform, constraints, policy

We would like to determine which policy/constraints to be enforced in GCP.

Is there any way to list all the Organization policy constraints available in GCP?

Comment: Yes , Please see this [link](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints) public documentation for all the Organization policy constraints available in GCP

Comment: If you already have project in production, I recommend you to activate the org policies on a project or a folder in acceptance to be sure that you break nothing!!

Answer (score 2):

You can find all available Organization Policy Constraints that are supported by Google Cloud services in the [following documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints).

You may also find this helpful:

> To learn more about the core concepts of organization policy:
>
> Read the [overview of organization policy](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/overview).
>
> Read about [what constraints are](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/understanding-constraints).
>
> Read [how to use constraints to create organization policies](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/using-constraints).
>
> Read about how [hierarchical evaluation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/understanding-hierarchy) works.

Comment: In Azure, we are able to create audit policy eg." Latest TLS version should be used in your Web App", in GCP, how can we create a similar policy? The Organization policy constraints seem to have only very limited constraints.

Comment: Can you give specific example of what policy / constraint you need ?

Comment: If you're just concerned with TLS you can't limit them with organization policy in any way but ou can use [SSL policies on the project level](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-policies-concepts).

Comment: How about policies as below? 
Keys should have expiration dates set
 Ensure that 'Python version' is the latest, if used as a part of the Web app
 Ensure that 'PHP version' is the latest, if used as a part of the WEB app
 Ensure that 'Java version' is the latest, if used as a part of the WEB app
 Ensure that 'HTTP Version' is the latest, if used to run the Web app
 Authentication should be enabled on your web app
 Secrets should have expiration dates set
 Web Application should only be accessible over HTTPS

Comment: For the moment there's no such feature but you can raise a new feature request on [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).

Comment: +1  @PJS . Did you find any way to setup such audit policies ? its possible in azure using azure policies but in GCP , I don't see similar thing. Org policies are on high level.